Create a ticket burndown chart with easyBI
I am using eazyBI to track my created and resolved Jira tickets.
Now, I am facing a serious problem in creating a ticket error curve.
I have a table with several rows indicating the calender weeks of the year, e.g.
CW 01-24
CW 02-24
...
CW 52-24
For each CW I wanted to define two report specific calculated member formula, which basically do the following.

Count the number of relevant tickets for my project, being created in or before CW x-24.
Count the number of relevant tickets for my project, being closed in or before CW x-24.

How, can I create such a measure in eazyBI with and MDX expression. Can I maybe just perform some kind of SELECT command to accomplish the task.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiDimensional_eXpressions
https://docs.eazybi.com/eazybi
